# General solution to null-divergence equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

I am interested in whether each component of a divergenceless vector can itself be written as a divergence.  My motivation for this question is the characterization of so-called *trivial conservation laws* in physics.  I suspect this representation is general, but I have not made much progress in a proof.

**Overview**

Consider the following differential equation for a vector $M$ depending on a set of independent variables $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and an arbitrary smooth vector field $u=(u^1,u^2,...,u^p)$ and its derivatives $\partial u=(u^1_1,u^1_2,...,u^p_n)$:
\begin{align}\label{1}\tag{1}
\sum_{i=1}^nD_iM^i(x,u,\partial u(x),...,\partial^m u(x))=0.
\end{align}
Here, $D_i=\partial_i+u^j_i\partial_{u^j}+...$ denotes a "total derivative", and $\partial^ku$ denotes the set of $k$-th order derivatives of $u$.

**Conjecture**:

The general solution to \eqref{1} for $M$ is as follows:
\begin{align}\label{2}\tag{2}
M^i=\sum_{j\neq i}D_jN^{ij}(x,u,\partial u,...,\partial^q u),\quad 1\le i\le n,
\end{align}
where each $N^{ij}=-N^{ji}$ is some function in an anti-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, and $q\ge m-1$ is some integer.

By "general solution", I mean that if \eqref{1} has a solution $M$, then there exist functions $N$ such that \eqref{2} holds.

**Progress**

It is clear that \eqref{2} is a *particular solution* to \eqref{1}.  That it is the general solution is straightforward to derive when $m=1$.  We can do this by expanding \eqref{1} using the chain rule and equating coefficients of higher order derivatives to zero.  However, this problem quickly becomes intractable as $m$ is increased.  I am wondering if there is a more elegant and general way to approach this problem.

Comment: Just a complement to Robert Bryant's answer. Once you convert (using Hodge duality) your $M^i$ and $N^{ij}$ tensor to differential forms and divergence operators to exterior derivatives, you are essentially asking whether there exists a "Poincaré lemma" for the de Rham complex on $u$-dependent differential forms. The theory of the _variational bicomplex_, expounded in I. Anderson's notes, was created to precisely answer that question.

Comment: An impatient physicist might also appreciate explicit and accessible formulas that go along with a more pedagogical introduction. Such formulas can be found, for instance, in the appendices of the following papers: [hep-th/9601124](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9601124), [hep-th/0111246](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111246).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is 'yes', that is the general solution.  This is one of the basic results in the theory of the variational bicomplex.  It is a statement of the vanishing of a certain cohomology group in the variational bicomplex.  A good place to look for the proof would be in say, these [lectures](http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/mathsci_facpub/32/) by Ian Anderson on the variational bicomplex.